# Infinite expression 1/0.^(1/4) encountered in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to solve very simple system of coupled differential equations using the `NDSolve` function, but I am getting `"Infinite expression 1/0.^(1/4) encountered."`

Any idea how to solve the problem? I was looking for solutions where people suggested to shift the `"Initial boundary point"` or by using the `Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" ->.....`. Could not manage to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

The code is as follows:

```
alphaphi = 2*10^-13;
MX = 1.15*10^-12;
Mphi = 10^13;
alphaX = 10^-2;
gstar = 200;
HubbleI = Mphi;
Mpl = 1.22*10^19;

phiI = (3/(8*Pi))*Mpl^2/Mphi^2 *HubbleI^2/Mphi^2;

T[x] = (30/(gstar*Pi^2))^(1/4)*Mphi*R[x]^(1/4)/x;
Xeq[x] = MX^3/Mphi^3 *(2*Pi)^(-3/2)*x^3*(T[x]/MX)^(3/2)*
Exp[-MX/T[x]];
c1 = Sqrt[3/(8*Pi)]*Mpl*alphaphi/Mphi;
c2 = c1*Mphi*alphaX/(MX*alphaphi);
c3 = c2*Mphi/MX;

sol = NDSolve[{D[phi[x], x] == -c1*x*phi[x]/Sqrt[phi[x]*x + R[x]], 
D[R[x], x] == 
 c1*x^2*phi[x]/Sqrt[phi[x]*x + R[x]] + 
  c2*x^-1*(X[x]^2 - Xeq[x]^2)/Sqrt[phi[x]*x + R[x]], 
D[X[x], x] == -c3*x^-2*(X[x]^2 - Xeq[x]^2)/Sqrt[phi[x]*x + R[x]], 
phi[1] == phiI, R[1] == 0, X[1] == 0}, {phi, R, X}, {x, 1, 10^5}];

Plot[Evaluate[{phi[x], R[x], X[x]} /. sol], {x, 1, 10^5}, 
PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you know that you're dividing by `R[x]^(1/4)`, since it's your equations.  And therefore I assume the question is how to integrate the system.  Since the division occurs inside an exponential and the argument of the exponential approaches negative infinity at `R[1] == 0`, the term stays bounded and approaches zero.  One solution is to rewrite the `Xeq` function so that it is zero when `R` is zero.  We also have to rewrite the `T` function.

```
Clear[Xeq, T];
T[x_, r_] := (30/(gstar*Pi^2))^(1/4)*Mphi*r^(1/4)/x;
Xeq[_, r_ /; r == 0] = 0.;
Xeq[x_?NumericQ, r_] := 
  MX^3/Mphi^3*(2*Pi)^(-3/2)*x^3*(T[x, r]/MX)^(3/2)*Exp[-MX/T[x, r]];
```

To get past `x == 1`, we need to set the option `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`.

```
alphaphi = 2*10^-13;
MX = 1.15*10^-12;
Mphi = 10^13;
alphaX = 10^-2;
gstar = 200;
HubbleI = Mphi;
Mpl = 1.22*10^19;

phiI = (3/(8*Pi))*Mpl^2/Mphi^2*HubbleI^2/Mphi^2;

Clear[Xeq, T];
T[x_, r_] := (30/(gstar*Pi^2))^(1/4)*Mphi*r^(1/4)/x;
Xeq[_, r_ /; r == 0] = 0.;
Xeq[x_?NumericQ, r_] := 
  MX^3/Mphi^3*(2*Pi)^(-3/2)*x^3*(T[x, r]/MX)^(3/2)*Exp[-MX/T[x, r]];

c1 = Sqrt[3/(8*Pi)]*Mpl*alphaphi/Mphi;
c2 = c1*Mphi*alphaX/(MX*alphaphi);
c3 = c2*Mphi/MX;

eqns = {D[phi[x], x] == -c1*x*phi[x]/Sqrt[phi[x]*x + R[x]], 
   D[R[x], x] == 
    c1*x^2*phi[x]/Sqrt[phi[x]*x + R[x]] + 
     c2*x^-1*(X[x]^2 - Xeq[x, R[x]]^2)/Sqrt[phi[x]*x + R[x]], 
   D[X[x], x] == -c3*
     x^-2*(X[x]^2 - Xeq[x, R[x]]^2)/Sqrt[phi[x]*x + R[x]], 
   phi[1] == phiI, R[1] == 0, X[1] == 0};

sol = NDSolve[eqns, {phi, R, X}, {x, 1, 10^5}, 
   Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
```

Plots, scaled to similar ranges:

```
Plot[
 {phi[x]/phi[10^5], R[x]/R[10^5], X[x]/X[0.99 * 10^5]} /. sol // Evaluate,
 {x, 1, 10^5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]